# Show partial View in pop up window

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC framework I need your support to succeed. I have a partial view and I need to show that partial view in a pop up window when a view is loaded. Please suggest me an optimal solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to at least show some dummy content in the popup ...I mean get code to show the pop up and then we can add code to show Partial view in it

Comment: Need more information. What you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [jQuery leanModal](http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/) plug-in to do that.
for example you can put your partial view in a `div` tag like :

```
<div id="modal">
    @Html.Partial("_Polling",Model)
</div>
```

JS :

```
$(function(){
    $('#modal').leanModal({ top: 70, closeButton: ".modal_close, .btnClose" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery UI dialog, you can do some thing like below. The sample code will have two ActionResult Method. One for Landing page and second one for popup view.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {

        return View();
   }

   public ActionResult PoupUp()
   {

        return View();
   }
}
```

---

Index View

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/jquery-ui.css">

<script>
$(function () {
var iframe = $('<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"        allowfullscreen></iframe>');
var dialog = $("<div></div>").append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    width: "auto",
    height: "auto",
    close: function () {
        iframe.attr("src", "");
    },
    buttons: {
        "Close": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }            
});
$(".dialog").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = $(this).attr("href");
    var title = $(this).attr("data-title");
    var width = $(this).attr("data-width");
    var height = $(this).attr("data-height");
    iframe.attr({
        width: +width,
        height: +height,
        src: src
    });
     dialog.dialog("option", "title", title).dialog("open");
    });
  });
  </script>

<a target="_blank" href="PopUp.cshtml" class="dialog" data-title="Page Titl" data-width="550" data-height="410">Click here</a>
```

Popup.cshtml

```
@{
   Layout = null;
 }

 Popup window.
```