# How to create a error modal pop inside a modal pop up in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am developing a website wherein I want ppl who visit the site to add their comments.

What I have done is, I have kept an add button and when the user clicks that button there will be a popup for adding comment. Now the user is not supposed to leave the field blank. So am doing the required validations in code behind and now I want to display an modal pop up error message when user tries to add comment without entering one of the field. How can I display the error message and then returning to back to the comments modal pop up..

The code I have come up with  is as below...

```
<asp:Button ID="addComment" runat="server" Text="Add Your Comment" OnClick="addComment_Click" style="margin-top:10px;" Height="30px" ToolTip="Add Your comment about us" Font-Bold="True" />

<asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
<ajaxtoolkit:modalpopupextender id="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" cancelcontrolid="btnCancel" targetcontrolid="addComment" popupcontrolid="Panel1" popupdraghandlecontrolid="PopupHeader" drag="false" backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG"></ajaxtoolkit:modalpopupextender>
<asp:panel id="Panel1" style="display: none" runat="server">
  <div class="HellowWorldPopup">
    <div class="PopupHeader" id="PopupHeader">
      <h3 style="color:white; font-family:'Palatino Linotype'">Add Your Comment</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="PopupBody">
      <p style="font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; margin-left:10px;">Your Name :</p>
      <p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" Text="" runat="server" Width="300px" style="margin-left:10px; font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; font-size:medium; font-style:italic"></asp:TextBox>
      </p>

      <p style="font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; margin-left:10px;">Your Comment:</p>
      <p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" Text="" runat="server" Width="400px" style="margin-left:10px;font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; max-height:100px; font-size:medium; resize:none; font-style:italic" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
      </p>

    </div>

    <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnOkay" Text="Done" OnClick="btnOkay_Click" style="font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:10px;  width:100px; height:30px; font-size:small;font-weight:700" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" style="font-family:'Palatino Linotype';width:100px; height:30px; margin-left:10px; font-size:small;font-weight:700" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />

  </div>

</asp:panel>
```

Please help me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try jQuery UI dialog instead of popup extender?

Comment: @Deepu.. Are you suggesting jqeury UI dialog only for error message display or for the whole stuff

Comment: I think the easier approach would be move the above code to a separate aspx page which will open in a jQuery UI dialog then you can have the validation popup inside that. Also, Can you do the validation in Client side so that you can avoid a server postback.

Comment: @Deepu I am already loading that page in an iframe and if a  load a separate page inside that page it will be more complex design. Anyways I will try it..

Comment: you can use this code which i posted before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229992/show-partial-view-in-pop-up-window/17230722#17230722

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem:

The modified code is as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="addComment" runat="server" Text="Add Your Comment" OnClick="addComment_Click" style="margin-top:10px;" Height="30px" ToolTip="Add Your comment about us" Font-Bold="True" CausesValidation="false" />

<asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
<ajaxtoolkit:modalpopupextender id="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" cancelcontrolid="btnCancel" targetcontrolid="addComment" popupcontrolid="Panel1" popupdraghandlecontrolid="PopupHeader" drag="false" backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG"
oncancelscript="ClearUI();" behaviorid="modalwithinput"></ajaxtoolkit:modalpopupextender>
<asp:panel id="Panel1" style="display: none" runat="server">
  <div class="HellowWorldPopup">
    <div class="PopupHeader" id="PopupHeader">
      <h3 style="color:white; font-family:'Palatino Linotype'">Add Your Comment</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="PopupBody">
      <p style="font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; margin-left:10px;">Your Name :</p>
      <p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" Text="" runat="server" Width="300px" style="margin-left:10px; font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; font-size:medium; font-style:italic"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" controltovalidate="txtName" errormessage="Please Enter your name" setfocusonerror="true" display="None"></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
        <ajaxtoolkit:validatorcalloutextender id="RequiredFieldValidator1_ValidatorCalloutExtender" runat="server" targetcontrolid="RequiredFieldValidator1" behaviorid="textValidator" enabled="True">
        </ajaxtoolkit:validatorcalloutextender>
      </p>

      <p style="font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; margin-left:10px;">Your Comment:</p>
      <p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" Text="" runat="server" Width="400px" style="margin-left:10px;font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; max-height:100px; font-size:medium; resize:none; font-style:italic" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" controltovalidate="txtComment" errormessage="Please Enter the Comment" setfocusonerror="true" display="None">
        </asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
        <ajaxtoolkit:validatorcalloutextender id="Validatorcalloutextender1" runat="server" targetcontrolid="RequiredFieldValidator2" behaviorid="textValidator1" enabled="True">
        </ajaxtoolkit:validatorcalloutextender>
      </p>

    </div>

    <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnOkay" Text="Done" OnClick="btnOkay_Click" style="font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:10px;  width:100px; height:30px; font-size:small;font-weight:700" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" style="font-family:'Palatino Linotype';width:100px; height:30px; margin-left:10px; font-size:small;font-weight:700" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />

  </div>

</asp:panel>
```

**[Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34996/ASP-NET-AJAX-Control-Toolkit-ModalPopupExtender-Co#3)**